# Do something when a property is set

Tags: c#, .net

imagine this:

```
public class Foo
{
    private IList<string> WasSet;

    public string Prop1 {get;set;}
    public bool Prop2 {get;set;}
...
    public int Prop900 {get;set;}
}
```

I would like to do:

```
WasSet.Add(PropertyName);
```

when a property is set.

is this possible without getting rid of auto-properties ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No - automatic properties are always just trivial implementations backed by a simple field, with no "triggers" etc. You'll have to write a full property. You may want to implement [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) to make it more general-purpose.

Answer (score 3):

You can't do this with auto properties, as the compiler is generating the appropriate backing field and accessors for you. You'd need to write the property yourself and handle the `set` functionality to update your list.